# How to get the set size, first and last record in a db2 ordered set with one call

Tags: sql, select, db2

I have a very big transaction table on DB2 v11, and I need to query a subset of it as efficiently as possible.  All I need is the total count of the set (not known in advance, it's based on criteria, lets say 1 day) and the ID of the first record, and the ID of the last record.
The old code was fetching the entire table, then just using the 1st record ID, and the last record ID, and size, and not making use of the rest. Now this code is timing out.  It's a complex query of several joins.
IS there a way to just fetch the size of the set, 1st record, last record all in one select query ?
I've read that reordering the list in order to fetch the 1st record(so fetch with Desc, then change to Asc) is not efficient.

sample table 1 TRANSACTION_RECORDS:

```
tdID     TIMESTAMP        name 
-------------------------------
123      2020-03-31       john 
234      2020-03-31       dan  
456      2020-03-01       Eve  
675      2020-04-01       joy
```

sample table 2 TRANSACTION_TYPE:

```
invoiceId   tdID      account
------------------------------
   897         123     abc  
   898         123     def  
   877         234     mnc  
   899         456     opp
```

Sample query

```
 select Min(tr.transaction_id), Max(tr.transaction_id)
   from TRANSACTION_RECORDS TR
      join TRANSACTION_TYPE TT
        on TR.tdID=tt.tdID      
  WHERE Date(TR.TIMESTAMP) = '2020-03-31'       
  group by tr.tdID
  order by TR.tdID ASC
```

This results in multiple columns, (but it requires the group by)

```
 123,123  
 234,234  
 456,456
```

What I want is:

```
 123,456
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected results (as tabular text), and your existing query. As it is, your question is quite broad.

Comment: `select min(id), max(id) from (... whatever tables and joins ...) where (whatever clauses) ... group by (whatever grouping you need)`; That should do what you need in one go...

Comment: You can even add the `count(*)` to know how big is your set... be aware that this will also take some time so essentially you will need to look at the explain plan of your query to make it more performatic...

Comment: see sample table/query, the min, max suggestion by Jorge doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: That,s because you are using the wrong grouping. If you remove the group by and the order by it should give you the result you want and also be more performatic since you don't need order by for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, for this query you don't need Group BY and neither Order by, just do:

```
select Min(tr.transaction_id), Max(tr.transaction_id)
   from TRANSACTION_RECORDS TR
      join TRANSACTION_TYPE TT
        on TR.tdID=tt.tdID      
  WHERE Date(TR.TIMESTAMP) = '2020-03-31'
```

It should work as expected

Comment: **This solution works**  :-) Thank You!  I don't have enough 'reputation votes' to mark the answer as Correct. Maybe someone else can click the upvote.

Comment: Hi @Carmigazit the option to accept will be available to you, it just takes around 15/20 minutes to be available IIRC.